# Calling sys.stderr.fileno(), after checking it is a python callable(), raises an AttributeError?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

This is really stumping me...
Here is the nub of the issue:

```
if hasattr(sys.stderr, 'fileno'):
    if callable(sys.stderr.fileno):
       i = sys.stderr.fileno()
```

When this statement executes, the 2 conditions pass, BUT the call to fileno() bombs with an AttributeError!!  Don't believe me?  Here's the stack dump:

> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>
> https://XXXX/YYYY/abcdef/hazards/NSP-F15-22/pdf/
>
> Django Version: 1.8.3 Python Version: 3.4.0 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'django.contrib.sites',  'django.contrib.flatpages',  'crispy_forms', 
>   'wkhtmltopdf',  'ckeditor',  ...) Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>   164. response = response.render() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
>   158. self.content = self.rendered_content File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wkhtmltopdf/views.py" in rendered_content
>   148.footer_filename=footer_filename) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wkhtmltopdf/views.py" in convert_to_pdf
>   107. return wkhtmltopdf(pages=[filename], **cmd_options) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py" in wkhtmltopdf
>
> **101. i = sys.stderr.fileno()**
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /abcdef/hazards/NSP-F15-22/pdf/
>
> Exception Value: **'mod_wsgi.Log' object has no attribute 'fileno'**

This all runs fine in our development environment running django dev server (i.e., not using wsgi).  But in our production env. we are serving a Django app on apache with mod_wsgi on Ubuntu.   All software latest stable versions (Ubuntu 14.04, python 3.4, django 1.8, libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 3.4-4ubuntu2.1.14.04.2) .

The issue seems to stem from wsgi replacing sys.stderr with a mod_wsgi.Log object.
Back in 2013 a patch was added in django-wkhtml2pdf to fix this issue...
see: https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf/pull/40

Unfortunately, as you can see from the code that is bombing on me, sys.stderr does have a 'fileno' attribute AND the fileno attribute is callable, BUT when you go to call it, Python raises the AttributeError exception shown above.

I'm at wits end - must be missing something really stupid here.  Would be ever so grateful for any hints on what might be the cause or where to look next.

Comment: According to python docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable), "... If this returns true, it is still possible that a call fails..."

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that `type(sys.stderr)` is an extension class (i.e. implemented in C instead of Python) which raises an AttributeError when you call its `fileno()` method.  Maybe it's trying to proxy to some other object (perhaps a mod_wsgi.Log instance) in a really strange/broken way?  I'd try to reduce this to a minimal test case and report a bug in Django.

Comment: Thanks for the tips - I'll try to reduce the test case.

Comment: You are using an ancient mod_wsgi version. Upgrading mod_wsgi would be a good start to see if the issue exists in latest versions. I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: OK - I narrowed it down to a simple test case: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/85   I will install the most recent code from your github repository and see if I can replicate it - thanks for replying Graham - awesome!

Comment: running now with mod_wsgi 4.4.13 - test case still failing.  See: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to be caused by by python 3 or an incompatibility with python 3.  Bug report currently in queue at https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/85.

Huge shout out to Kevin and Graham for quick and helpful responses.  Thank you!